# LinearLayout layout 2 textviews

Tags: android, layout, xamarin, textview

I want to try and get two textviews to be layout evenly like -

```
 _______________________
|Tom      Smith         |
|Peter    Johnson       |
|lkallls  sfd           |
|_______________________|
```

But mine looks like this which I don't want

```
 _______________________
|Tom        Smith       |
|Peter     Johnson      |
|lkallls     sfd        |
|_______________________|


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
        <TextView
            android:text="qweqweqwe"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvExVat" />
        <TextView
            android:text="qwe"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvTurnOver" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="aaaaaaaa"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvTurnOverToday" />
        <TextView
            android:text="sdfsd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/vTurnOverMtd" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I wasn't sure if I should use a Grid Layout or keep it linear?

Can someone please help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
            <TextView
                android:text="qweqweqwe"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvExVat" />
            <TextView
                android:text="qwe"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvTurnOver" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="aaaaaaaa"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvTurnOverToday" />
            <TextView
                android:text="sdfsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/vTurnOverMtd" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this code ,this should work as you wanted

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="John" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Jani" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Janardhan" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="John" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Jani" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Janardhan" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
        <TextView
            android:text="qweqweqwe"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvExVat" />
        <TextView
            android:text="qwe"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvTurnOver" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="aaaaaaaa"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvTurnOverToday" />
        <TextView
            android:text="sdfsd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/vTurnOverMtd" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```